# Numbers ignored when importing Excel to SQL Server in ASP.NET using OLEDB

Tags: asp.net, gridview, oledb

Here's the code I'm using to show the Excel data on a Gridview:

```
if (FileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName.Contains(".xls"))
{
   FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + "data.xls");
   string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + "data.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

   using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
      connection.Open();
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select ID FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
      DataTable raw = new DataTable();

      using (System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
         raw.Load(dr);
      }

      gv.DataSource = raw;
      gv.DataBind();
   }
}
```

This is what happens... I have this in my `data.xls` file:

```
ID
A-001
3929
B-001
```

When I upload that, the Gridview displays only these:

```
ID
A-001
B-001
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `IMEX=1` to your connection string.

It tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might affect excel sheet write access negative.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel